# Search on multiple columns a serie of value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database, every user can have 5 tags, which are int number from 1 to 37.

If an user has only one tag for example, the database shows that :

```
tag1 : 36
tag2 : 0
tag3 : 0
tag4 : 0
tag5 : 0
```

On "search user" page, you can choose from 1 to 5 tags (the input name is skill1 to skill5), and the page must shows the profile accordingly.

For now, it works well if you choose only one tag, with this request :

```
WHERE tag1 REGEXP '$skill1|$skill2|$skill3|$skill4|$skill5'
```

But I can't figure out how to make it work for 1 to 5 tags.

My goal is to have a request who seems :

```
WHERE (tag1 or tag2 or tag3 or tag4 or tag5) REGEXP '$skill1|$skill2|$skill3|$skill4|$skill5'
```

And, Is there a way to ponderate the results? For example, at first, the user have 4 tags of your search, then 3 tags, etc.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Does the search need to match anyone with all tags or anyone with any tags?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to ponderate the results. For a search with these tag, for example : 4,16,23,8,11 i want the request return all the people who have 5 of these tags, then all the people who have 4 of these tags, etc. But note that the search can also be 4,16,23,0,0 if the user of the site search only 3 tags.

Answer (score 3):

You have a poor data structure.  You should have a junction table with one row per entity and per tag.

You can do what you want as:

```
where tag1 in ($skill1, $skill2, $skill3, $skill4, $skill5) or
      tag2 in ($skill1, $skill2, $skill3, $skill4, $skill5) or
      tag3 in ($skill1, $skill2, $skill3, $skill4, $skill5) or
      tag4 in ($skill1, $skill2, $skill3, $skill4, $skill5) or
      tag5 in ($skill1, $skill2, $skill3, $skill4, $skill5)
order by ( (tag1 in ($skill1, $skill2, $skill3, $skill4, $skill5)) + 
           (tag2 in ($skill1, $skill2, $skill3, $skill4, $skill5)) + 
           (tag3 in ($skill1, $skill2, $skill3, $skill4, $skill5)) + 
           (tag4 in ($skill1, $skill2, $skill3, $skill4, $skill5)) + 
           (tag5 in ($skill1, $skill2, $skill3, $skill4, $skill5))
          ) desc
```

MySQL treats a boolean in a numeric context as a value of 1 for true and 0 for false.

Note:  You can do the same thing with `regexp` if you want the user input to allow regular expression pattern matches.

Comment: Thanks ! Edit : It's seems to work, but if I search only the tag 4 : skill1=4 skill2 =0, skill3=0, skill4=0 and skill5=0. And it returns my a user who have "3-0-0-0-0". it's not normal no ?

Comment: A search for tag "4" should not be returning tag "3".

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
select *
from
(select username, concat_ws('-',tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,'') as tags
from table
where username = 'nik'
and (tag1 > 0 OR tag2 > 0 OR tag3 > 0 OR tag4 > 0 OR tag5 > 0)
order by tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5) conc
where conc.tags REGEXP '$skill1-|$skill2-|$skill3-|$skill4-|$skill5-'
```

but using regexp is a bad idea

Comment: Why is it a bad idea ? Does your solution still work when, for example, we search the tag 12 and 28. So, if i search for every user if each tag is equal to 12,28,0,0 or 0, we will even return users who have no tags (0,0,0,0,0), no ?

Comment: With large amounts of data, the full scan will be performed, which degrades the performance of this solution

Comment: Also you need a separator for your tags.

Comment: added a delimiter and a condition for empty tags

Comment: Thanks ! Why there is a line "where username = 'nik'" ? I'm not sure to understand

Comment: this as an example for a specific user, you can and without this condition

Comment: Ok ! But it seems that your request finally return a lot of users, because if I search for only one tag, for example 4, we have skill1=4 skill2 =0, skill3=0, skill4=0 and skill5=0. And it returns my a user who have "3-0-0-0-0" because it's match all the conditions. Am i clear or not ?

Comment: Here it is worth reviewing the data storage structure :-)